# How can I resolve 'module not found error' in webpack?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, react-bootstrap

I have my reactjs app with react-bootstrap running on webpack 2. When I run the app I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./app/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2' in '/Users/me/reactjs_dutchboiler/app/css'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./app/css/bootstrap.css 6:4720-4774
 @ ./app/css/bootstrap.css
 @ ./app/app.jsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./app/app.jsx
```

The app was running without errors until I imported bootstrap.css. Now I get the error above.
It looks like webpack does not have the right loader installed? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is your answer. Install the right loader. I would try `url-loader`.

```
rules: [
//your loaders
{
    test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg)$/,
    use: 'url-loader'
}
```

Also, check if the file `glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2` is actually in the folder and that you have the right path to it.